what was Paul doing within the 3 years he went back to Damascus in Galatians 1:17-18?
Galatians 1:17-18
A description of what Paul did in those 3 years he was away before going to meet Peter and spending some days with him. In the vs 16, he says he consulted not with flesh and blood, and saw not any of the apostles.

Welcome to BHSX.  Thanks for joining the group.  Please remember to take the tour (link bottom left) to better understand how this site is different.

Also see https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/56852/did-paul-spend-3-years-in-arabia-or-damascus?r=SearchResults&s=1%7C73.1953

First, for completeness only, I have included a brief history of the apostle Paul in the first few years after his conversion in the appendix below.
The OP asks what Paul was doing in his self-imposed isolation in Arabia.  It appears that he left from Damascus and returned to Damascus.
The only information that we have about Paul's time in Arabia is that recorded in Gal 1:15-17, viz:

15 But when God, who set me apart from my mother’s womb and called me by His grace, was pleased 16 to reveal His Son in me so that I
might preach Him among the Gentiles, I did not rush to consult with
flesh and blood, 17 nor did I go up to Jerusalem to the apostles
who came before me, but I went into Arabia and later returned to
Damascus.

From this brief information we can definitely conclude that Paul did not consult with other humans ("flesh and blood").  That is, he spent the time essentially alone.
We are not told how long he spent in Arabia, but it appears that it was less than three years, perhaps only one year(???).  Ellicott offers these comments:

As to the time of the Apostle’s withdrawal, and its duration, little
can be said beyond the fact that it must have come within the three
years that intervened between his conversion and the first visit to
Jerusalem. ...
The patristic commentators seem to have held, for the most part, to
the belief that the object of his visit to Arabia was to preach to the
heathen there; but the whole context of the Epistle shows that it was
rather for solitary meditation and communion with God.

More than this is speculation.
APPENDIX: Early Chronology of the Apostle Paul
As best I can work out, based on the record we have in Acts 9-15 and Gal 1 & 2, the sequence of events following Paul's conversion goes something like this. (The record in Acts is not continuous).

Saul experiences his conversion experience on the road to Damascus, Acts 9:1-19
Immediately afterward Saul preached Jesus in the synagogues, Acts 9:20-22
How long he remained in Damascus preaching in the synagogues in unknown but it was probably a few months(??). He then went to Arabia for an unknown time, presumably to clarify his thinking. Gal 1:17
Saul then returned to Damascus. Gal 1:17. It is not clear whether the events of Acts 9:23-25 (the plot to kill Saul) was before or after the trip Arabia. I am inclined to the latter because it was after "many days" (Acts 9:23). In any case, at this point, Paul has thus far confined himself to synagogues. It was at this point that he decided to leave for Jerusalem.
Paul goes to Jerusalem 3 years after his conversion (Gal 1:18, Acts 1:26-29) to meet Cephas/Peter and other leaders. Saul is still only dealing with Jews and not gentiles. Acts 9:29.
Paul then travels to Syria and Cilicia via Tarsus. Gal 1:21-24, Acts 9:30.
The Church enjoyed a time of peace. Acts 9:31. During this next period, Acts is silent about the activities of Saul.
Peter miraculously heals Aeneas and resurrects Tabitha at Lydda. Acts 9:32-43 Peter is called to Cornelius and baptizes the first gentile at Caesarea. Acts 10. Peter is called to Jerusalem to explain why he had entered a gentile's house and then baptized a gentile. After explaining about the action of the Holy Spirit, the leaders had no further objection. Acts 11:1-18. There is no further record of Peter ever preaching to gentiles after this incident.
Attention then shifts to Antioch and the developing tension over the role, if any, gentiles should have in the Gospel message. Acts 11:19-26. It was during this time that Barnabas went to get Saul in Tarsus (v25) and brought him to Antioch. It was at this time that Saul and Barnabas began preaching to gentiles.
Because of a famine, Saul and Barnabas are sent with gifts to Jerusalem. Acts 11:27-30. It is probable that this was the trip to Jerusalem referred to in Gal 2:1, fourteen years after Paul's conversion. It was at this Jerusalem meeting that Paul agreed with Peter an amicable division of labour - Paul would preach to the gentiles while Peter would preach to the Jews, Gal 2:9.
Saul returns from Jerusalem to Antioch. Acts 12:25
Saul/Paul and Barnabas are sent off on their first missionary journey Acts 13:2 - 14:28, preaching to gentiles, returning to Antioch.
The Jerusalem council is called to debate circumcision. Acts 15.


+1 and thanks. However my reading of "rushed to consult with flesh and blood" is specifically a reference to Paul's not taking advice from the leaders of the church or anyone else as to what he should preach. I think he probably did not isolate himself but continued to witness to both  his fellow Jews and non-Jews. He withdrew to "Arabia" because it was virgin territory where his spiritual elders would not be looking over his shoulder, so to speak.

@DanFefferman - you may be correct.  The reason I thought that it meant time for reflection was two-fold - it was a major change in his thinking and second because he always boasted that his message was from God and not men.  However, I do not deny your assertion at all - but he never returned there (as he did to other missionary fields).  That would have made his "first" missionary tour in Acts 13 his second.

I believe Paul tells us in verses 11 and 12 what this purpose was:
Galatians 1:11-12

But I certify you, brethren, that the gospel which was preached of me is not after man.
12 For I neither received it of man, neither was I taught it, but by the revelation of Jesus Christ.

Romans 16:25-26

Now to him that is of power to stablish you according to my gospel, and the preaching of Jesus Christ, according to the revelation of the mystery, which was kept secret since the world began,
26 But now is made manifest, and by the scriptures of the prophets, according to the commandment of the everlasting God, made known to all nations for the obedience of faith:

The previously hidden "mysteries" found in Paul's "my gospel" were revealed to Paul to now make manifest for the world.  Paul went to see Peter to inform him of how Christ's newly revealed instructions from heaven had changed a bit since Christ's earthly ministry to Israel.
2 Corinthians 5:16

Wherefore henceforth know we no man after the flesh: yea, though we have known Christ after the flesh, yet now henceforth know we him no more.

Galatians 2:7-9

But contrariwise, when they saw that the gospel of the uncircumcision was committed unto me, as the gospel of the circumcision was unto Peter;
8 (For he that wrought effectually in Peter to the apostleship of the circumcision, the same was mighty in me toward the Gentiles:)
9 And when James, Cephas, and John, who seemed to be pillars, perceived the grace that was given unto me, they gave to me and Barnabas the right hands of fellowship; that we should go unto the heathen, and they unto the circumcision.

This was the result of Israel rejecting Jesus Christ being their Messiah, and culminated at the stoning death of Stephen, that Paul himself (Saul of Tarsus) consented unto (Acts 8:1).
Romans 11:11

I say then, Have they stumbled that they should fall? God forbid: but rather through their fall salvation is come unto the Gentiles, for to provoke them to jealousy.

Gentiles, based on Paul's gospel, were then (and now) offered salvation freely (Eph 2:8-9).  It is the free gift of God through having faith alone in Christ alone, and without having to first hear of God through Israel, who was (and will someday still be) God's promised nation of priests to the world.
Ephesians 3:1-6

For this cause I Paul, the prisoner of Jesus Christ for you Gentiles,
2 If ye have heard of the dispensation of the grace of God which is given me to you-ward:
3 How that by revelation he made known unto me the mystery; (as I wrote afore in few words,
4 Whereby, when ye read, ye may understand my knowledge in the mystery of Christ)
5 Which in other ages was not made known unto the sons of men, as it is now revealed unto his holy apostles and prophets by the Spirit;
6 That the Gentiles should be fellowheirs, and of the same body, and partakers of his promise in Christ by the gospel:


The Bible does not gives us direct information about what Paul was doing during his three years in "Arabia" but it is useful to know something about that region during the time in question. This may provide clues as to Paul's activities during this time. I believe Paul continued witnessing to local Jewish communities during this time rather than withdrawing to meditate or preaching primarily to "the heathen."
Two kingdoms existed in the region prior to Roman rule. One was the land of the Nabateans, the other of the Idumeans. Both regions included sizeable towns as well as populations of farmers and nomadic herders. Idumea had been conquered c. 110 b.c.e. by the Jewish king John Hyrcanus I. As a result, it had largely converted to Judaism and even produced the Herodian line of Jewish rulers during the Roman period. The Nabatean kingdom, on the other hand, remained independent and did not convert to Judaism. While it is possible that Paul would have spent time in Nabatean towns, I think it is more likely that his time in "Arabia" would have been spent in Idumea, where Judaism was the norm.  At the same time, former Idumean towns are a distinct possibility because of their proximity to Damascus. The borders of the territories are uncertain as they overlap with Roman administrative districts, but the map below may help us understand what Paul refers to. It should be noted that Nabatea once extended farther north, almost reaching to Damascus.

Several commentators (including @Dottard) suggest that Paul's time in Arabia was spent working out the details of his gospel. If one pictures him meditating for long periods as a kind of proto-monk, I do not think this is necessarily the case, as there were ample opportunities for evangelical activities and attempts at congregation-building in the area. Rather, perhaps we should envision a kind of praxis, where Paul attempted to share his message with the people of the region, both Jews and non-Jews, working out his "gospel to the Gentiles" in the process.
Conclusion: Rather than primarily meditating on what he would later call "his gospel," (Romans 16:25) it is likely that during his time in "Arabia" Paul continued to witness to his fellow Jews in the region while at the same time refining his teachings about Christ for gentiles.
